# How to prevent Xcode from removing break points when code line removed?

Tags: xcode, xcode8

When I add a fully featured break point for debugging sometimes I accidentally remove it by dragging between other break points or just by removing the code on that line. Is there a way to prevent Xcode from removing my breakpoints when the code line removed? Or is there a way to cmd+Z to make it come back? If not, is there an Xcode extension for that?